# Reading a specific line from a Plist

Tags: objective-c, string, random, plist

Hi I've been looking all over and can't seem to find an answer to my issue. I have very little experience with programming, especially Objective-C.
In my app there is a `plist` with a certain number of strings. When the user taps a button, the program counts the number of strings in the plist, creates a random number within that range, and is supposed to read the line of the plist with that specific number.
Say if there were 20 strings in the plist, and the app generated the number 5, then the app is supposed to read the 5th string in the plist.

Is there a way to do such a thing or is there another, more efficient way to accomplish this? ANY help is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: 
In my .h file I have

```
NSMutableArray* myArray;
int plistCount;
int randomNumber; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* myArray;
```

And in my .m file I have

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myplist" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray* tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.myArray = tmpArray;
plistCount=[self.resorts count];
randomNumber=arc4random() % plistCount;
```

I dont know where to go from here.

Comment: please post your code attempt...

Comment: Yeah sure. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString * randomString = self.myArray[arc4random_uniform(self.myArray.count)];
```

The above code is selecting a random element from `self.myArray`.

`arc4random_uniform` generates a number between 0 and the argument (excluded) so using `self.myArray.count` as a bound you'll get a valid random index for the array.

**NOTE**

You have to explicitly check that the array is never empty in order for the above code to work, since
`arc4random_uniform(0)` returns `0`, therefore in case of an empty array it will generate a `NSRangeException`.

Comment: I will definitely try this as soon as I can. Thank you for the help!